# Recursively Refiling All Subtrees with @Tag to a Destination (Org-Mode)

Tags: org-mode

Suppose we have:

```
* Parent
** Child1 :@Tag:
*** Child of Child1
** Child2
*** Child of Child2
** Child3 :@Tag:
*** Child of Child3
```

Is there a way to copy all subtrees of `* Parent` with tag `@Tag` to a destination (say `* Destination`), so that we get:

```
* Destination
** Child1 :@Tag:
*** Child of Child1
** Child3 :@Tag:
*** Child of Child3
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly `org-refile' isn't a programmatically friendly function.  What you want to do is generate a RFLOC parameter value for your desired target and use "Copy" as the MSG value.  Here's some code to do it programmatically.

I recommend using org ID's whenever possible to virtually eliminate any ambiguity in reference to headings.  First, create an ID for the destination and use that.

```
(let* ((target-heading "Destination")
       (target-marker (org-find-exact-headline-in-buffer target-heading))
       (target-id (save-excursion (goto-char target-marker)
                                  (org-id-get-create))))
  target-id)
;; => "22bdee5f-3c93-4ca7-b944-48db2ddc3538"
```

Then here is a function to help programmatically refile or copy those headings:

```
(defun ebpa/refile-matches-to-heading (match target-heading-id &optional scope copy)
  "Refile all headings within SCOPE (per `org-map-entries') to TARGET-HEADING-ID."
  (if-let (target-marker (org-id-find target-heading-id t))
      (let* ((target-rfloc (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer target-marker)
                             (goto-char target-marker)
                             (list (org-get-heading)
                                   (buffer-file-name (marker-buffer target-marker))
                                   nil
                                   target-marker)))
             (headings-to-copy (org-map-entries (lambda () (point-marker)) match scope)))
        (mapc
         (lambda (heading-marker)
           (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer heading-marker)
             (goto-char heading-marker)
             (org-refile nil nil target-rfloc (when copy "Copy"))))
         headings-to-copy)
        (message "%s %d headings!"
                 (if copy "Copied" "Refiled")
                 (length headings-to-copy)))
    (warn "Could not find target heading %S" target-heading-id)))
```

You can use it in the following way:

```
(ebpa/refile-matches-to-heading
 "TAGS={@Tag}"
 "22bdee5f-3c93-4ca7-b944-48db2ddc3538"
 'file
 t)
```

Comment: This works, but it has a weird effect of joining header lines together (from the original org header that you're trying to partially refile) after running. I skimmed your code and don't see anything that could affect the layout of the original org-headers though. Any ideas of what's causing this?

Comment: @George  Sorry about that. The bug in my code is early use of `marker-position`.  I'll fix it shortly.  (Fixed)  I don't know why I thought org-refile would accept a position, but not a marker.